# Setcookie Different for Different URLs

Tags: php, setcookie

Hi I have a problem with set cookie. I have a url like this

```
http://www.myweb.com/series/Setayesh/Part-1
```

At this url I check if the cookie is set or not by this

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename']))
{
 //Perform some operations
}
else
{
setcookie('cookiename',$value,time()+36000)
}
```

It works well  for all urls like

```
http://www.myweb.com/series/Setayesh/Part-1
http://www.myweb.com/series/Setayesh/Part-1
http://www.myweb.com/series/Setayesh/Part-1
and so on
```

But when url becomes

```
http://www.myweb.com/series/Pezeshkan/Part-1
```

The if condition doesn't executes it always come in else condition in same browser. What is this problem? When I am setting cookie I am not setting any url then why it behaves different for such condition.

Comment: Is the value of the cookie ever `NULL`?

Comment: No when the url changes as my mentioned in question, it is null otherwise not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that the cookie is set to the path that you are requesting. In your case you are issuing the cookie for the path

```
/series/Setayesh/Part-1
```

So if that path changes to

```
/series/Pezeshkan/Part-1
```

you cannot see the cookie anymore as it was issued for another path. The setcookie function has a fourth parameter "path" which allows to specify the path explicitely. If you set it to "/" the cookie will be valid for the whole domain:

```
setcookie('cookiename',$value,time()+36000, '/')
```

This should solve the issue.